# Как программно получить свободный объём оперативной памяти в android?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Как программно получить свободный объём оперативной памяти в android? Т.е. именно сколько доступно RAM в телефоне

Comment: оперативная память

Answer (score 2):

Например, так:

```
MemoryInfo memoryInfo = new MemoryInfo();
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)getActivity(). getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
activityManager.getMemoryInfo(memoryInfo);
Log.i("Memory", "Free RAM="+memoryInfo.availMem);
Log.i("Memory", "Total RAM="+memoryInfo.totalMem);
```