# Определение общего объема оперативной памяти с помощью вызовов Java классов из C# (Unity)

Tags: java, c#, android, unity3d-android

Появилась необходимость узнать общий объем оперативной памяти устройства, которое будет запускать скомпилированную версию приложения, т.к все приложение на Unity, решил вызывать Java код из C# путем использования классов AndroidJavaClass и AndroidJavaObject. Сам принцип работы этих классов понятен, т.к уже писалась система с их использованием. Непонятно одно, принцип получения информации об объеме памяти. Нашел пример кода на Java, в теме: [Как программно получить свободный объём оперативной памяти в android?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/769339/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%91%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2-android)

Ниже пример кода из темы:

```
MemoryInfo memoryInfo = new MemoryInfo();
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)getActivity(). getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
activityManager.getMemoryInfo(memoryInfo);
Log.i("Memory", "Free RAM="+memoryInfo.availMem);
Log.i("Memory", "Total RAM="+memoryInfo.totalMem);
```

Однако не могу получить доступ к полю totalMem.

Вот пример моего кода:

```
javaClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
javaObject = javaClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
androidActivityManagerMemoryInfo = new AndroidJavaClass("android.app.ActivityManager$MemoryInfo");
totalMem = androidActivityManagerMemoryInfo.Get<long>("totalMem");
```

Т.е я получаю текущее activity приложения, нахожу android класс ActivityManager.MemoryInfo и пытаюсь от него получить поле totalMem, в соответствии с документацией о классе и назначении поля https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.MemoryInfo, но в зависимости от различных правок в коде получаю либо отсутствие ссылки на объект, либо 0 (опять же почему 0 - неизвестно).

Comment: не  уверен  насчет  андроида. Но в java есть jstat,есть JMX, ну и самые простые Runtime.getFreeMemory и парочка других методов

Comment: @Труфальдино я писал систему для определения root на устройствах по подобному методу, там с получением доступа к классам и полям android.os.Build, android.os.Build.Version и java.lang.System не возникало однако здесь почему то, я вот так встрял...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зачем искать и переписывать java код, если можно найти готовый для юнитов:

```cs
const uint kMegabyte = 1048576u;
 
AndroidJavaObject getMemoryInfo()
{
    AndroidJavaClass unityPlayerClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unityPlayerClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    AndroidJavaObject systemService = currentActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getSystemService", "activity");
    AndroidJavaObject memoryInfo = new AndroidJavaObject("android.app.ActivityManager$MemoryInfo");
    systemService.Call("getMemoryInfo", memoryInfo);
 
    return memoryInfo;
}
 
int getAvailMemory()
{
    using (var memInfo = getMemoryInfo())
    {
        return (int)(memInfo.Get<long>("availMem") / kMegabyte);
    }
}
 
int getTotalMemory()
{
    using (var memInfo = getMemoryInfo())
    {
        return (int)(memInfo.Get<long>("totalMem") / kMegabyte);
    }
}
```

Источник:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/systeminfo-systemmemorysize-return-weird-value-on-samsung-s9.527096/

Comment: о, ну я собственно так и начинал (второй код листинг), мне как раз было необходимо узнать насчет system service и memory info